# How do I send files with Telegram Bots using AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telegram

I am trying to send an mp3 file using a telegram bot.

When I run it locally using node in terminal this code works perfectly fine:

```
'use strict'
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf('Token')

bot.command('audio', (ctx) => {
        ctx.replyWithAudio({source: './media/song.mp3'})
    })

const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env
bot.startWebhook('/', null, PORT)
```

However, when I deploy this as an AWS Lambda function I get the following error:

```
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4 events.js:183
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4       ^
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4 Error: write after end
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:622:15)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:617:10)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at MultipartStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at MultipartStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at MultipartStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:475:10)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at flow (_stream_readable.js:846:34)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:828:3)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  Apr 29th 12:24:12pm ERRO staging 4     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I am pretty sure this is because I don't understand how files are stored when I deploy the lambda function. How are directories saved so I can retrieve them? Is this even possible?

My zip bundle contains the following directories:

[image: Zip file]

For this bot I used [apex up](https://up.docs.apex.sh/) to deploy and [telegraf](http://telegraf.js.org) to write the code.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code. Lambda has 512MB for use, using `/tmp`. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, is the MP3 in the zip bundle?

Comment: @dpwrussell I added the information you asked for. I did not understand the way you told me to get the zip bundle, instead I used [$ up build](https://up.docs.apex.sh/#commands), which gave me the zip file.

Comment: Sorry, I'd written it in Python instead of javascript for some reason. I wasn't saying you should build the bundle in a different way, but showing how to get a file when the lambda is running that is in the bundle. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your MP3 is in the zip bundle you uploaded, then you can find that and anything else in the bundle when the lambda is running.

In the lambda you can get the directory containing the unzipped bundle with `process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`. Your file will be relative to that.

```
bot.command('audio', (ctx) => {
    ctx.replyWithAudio({
        source: process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT + '/media/song.mp3'
    })
})
```